# Autolayout two views divide the additional space

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder, autolayout

I have two views inside the `UIViewController` view property. These two views are vertical to each other. One is at the top and other is beneath the top one. Now what i want is, when the screen size is changed for example, when app runs on iPhone 4s and on iPhone 5, i want both the views to equally divide the remaining space. None of them has a fixed height value.
Now if i set the `Vertical Content Compression Priority` of both view to same value let's say 747 and `Vertical Content Hugging Priority` of two view to the same value then Interface gives me error that i should increase the `Vertical Content Compression Priority` of one of the view to some different value.

I want both the views to share the additional space or shrink accordingly.

Can some bode help how i can achieve this?

Comment: You could use the <= priority constant provided in autolayout. So you will have a fix min as well as max value for height and you could apply it using IB in xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following tutorial ist one of the best I found so far explaining autolayout. In this tutorial you find a detailed explanation of how to achieve the behaviour you describe. Two views with fixed distances consuming the available space on the screen:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Perhaps this helps you finding a solution for your problem.